# using Regular expression need to remove specific special characters

Tags: java, python

My input is:

```
^(LD-WBACG-)(.*?)(-Professional|-Admin|-Standard|-Viewer)
```

and I wanted the output like:

```
LD-WBACG-(.*?)(-Professional|-Admin|-Standard|-Viewer)
```

from input I need to remove the first occurrence of cap (`^`) and braces `()`. i.e. `^(` and `)`.

Comment: Are you attempting to remove characters from a regular expression using a regular expression?

Comment: yes, I can do this by using string in Python.. but wanted to achieve this using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `string.replace()` function to replace first occurrence of each of the character can be a solution. Something like:

```
replace("^","",1);
```

Comment: need to use regular expression